# changing php version on acquia dev desktop?

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I am using acquia dev desktop and my site was using PHP 5.2.17. When I installed the Rooms module it would not enable as it requires PHP 5.3
On the dev desktop I switched to PHP 5.3.
However when I look at the Status report it is still showing that the dev site is using 5.2.17?
Dev desktop shows 5.3 - Site shows 5.2.17
Any ideas?

Comment: Switch to MAMP, they have a UI switch from 5.2 to 5.3 that works well. No reason to stick with a development environment that restricts your options when many other options are available.

Comment: Forgot to mention that if you are using Acquia hosting you might be stuck with 5.2.17 anyway, which is probably their reason for using that in dev desktop.

Comment: The Acquia dev desktop lets you switch between 5.2 and 5.3. The site build was started off on 5.2 and it was easy to switch to 5.3 (which is what is showing on the desktop dashboard). However the site's status report shows 5.2?

Comment: This is of course a very old question, but situation in 2020 is you can switch between PHP 5.5, 5.6, 7.0, 7.1 and 7.2 (there's supposed to be 7.3 support, but it's not available on macOS yet it would seem…)  I'd also highly recommend [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/valet) for testing Drupal sites, which will do everything except setup your MYSQL database.